# CSS transition - expanding child div to its parent width and height

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here's what I got up to in terms of starting point - https://codepen.io/illianyh/pen/bGpJgma.

```css
/*For IE CSS3 transition property works starting IE10*/
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; margin: 0;text-align: center}
h1 {font-weight: normal;color: #6A5953}
kbd {font-size: 0.9em;display:inline-block;line-height:1.1;}

div, h2, img {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
h2 {
  color: #E39F81;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFE3BD;
}
h2:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFE3BD, 2px 2px 0 #FFE3BD, 3px 3px 0 #FFE3BD, 4px 4px 0 #FFE3BD, 5px 5px 0 #FFE3BD;
  
}

.parent {
  width: 560px;
  height: 386px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 50%; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 153px;
}

.four {
  width: 423px;
  height: 248px;
  background-color: #95A1B1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.four:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 15px -10px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS3 Transition examples</h1>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="box"><div class="four"><kbd>width, height, box-shadow</kbd></div></div>

</div>
```

How do I make the child to expand itself towards, inside and on top of the its parent instead of expanding itself on the outside.

Here's a diagram what I'm trying to achieve:

Initial state (the arrows represent the direction of the child expanding):

[image]

this is the final state and in the end the child div has the same width and height of the parent. The parent is now hidden behind the child:
[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused because the element with class 'parent' is not actually the parent of anything. I assume your html should look something like this: `<div class="parent">
<div class="box"></div></div>` with the element to be animated an actual child of the 'parent' element?

Comment: I'm only calling it parent as in the end the small div is going to stack on top on the bigger div. I guess it can be called `first div`.. `second div`.. `neighbouring divs`

Comment: To be clear, the solution probably involves placing the 'child' as an actual child of the parent element. Is there a good reason for not doing it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Parent has fixed size with position relative
- Child has percentage or any size type with position absoulte and top left positions related to parent fixed size (could be even percentage parent)
- Transition works over known sizes

Here is an example i fixed for you: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/xIsra/pen/mdPgRgm)

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
  width: 560px;
  height: 386px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.child {
  position:absolute;
  background: blue;
  height:70%;
  width: 50%;
  right: -20%;
  top:15%;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 15px -10px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}
.parent:hover .child{
  top: 0%;
  right: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
.text{
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is first to place the child inside the parent with position and size so that it is completely congruent with the parent (Let's call this the *actual* position of the child). Then you use the transform property with the scale and translate functions to position the child at its *starting* position. Finally, when the user hovers over the child, you reset the translate and scale values back to their defaults. This has the result of animating the child to the actual position.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  transform: translate(100px, 53px) scale(0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  background: orange;
}

.box:hover {
   transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS3 Transition examples</h1>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

This is a simplified version of the [FLIP](https://css-tricks.com/animating-layouts-with-the-flip-technique/) technique.